# Sending Scroll event to another application

Tags: java, android

I think is question is bit crazy, I basically want to send scroll event from my app to another app ( eg chrome ). So basically if chrome is opened and when user press vol up or down button, my background activity listen for that button event and if its a up event then it will scroll chrome opened webpage up or down. I am not sure is that possible because I was reading through some doc's from google and its all saying we need root permission to sent event from one app to another. I don't have any code yet. So any one know this is possible with android api ?

Thanks

Comment: look for "injecting events" and "accessibility manager" on google.

also look how the gamepad-> touchscreen events helper applications like the one from 8bitdo work(dump it in a decompiler).

Comment: @LassiKinnunen man that what I was looking for, thanks again

Answer (score 1):

I cannot answer in the context of chrome. However, You can essentially serialize what you need and send it via the intent system to another application.

As an example, in your first application, you receive the touch event

```
boolean onTouch(MotionEvent event){
    if(event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
        Intent startOtherApplication = new Intent();
        startOtherApplication.putExtra("ACTION_UP_X",event.getX());
        startOtherApplication.putExtra("ACTION_UP_Y",event.getY());
        startOtherApplication.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.your.other.application", "com.your.other.application.ActivityYouWantToHandleTouch"));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

You would then extract the intent in the Activity (ActivityYouWantToHandleTouch) in your other Application.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent fetchedIntent = getIntent();
    boolean hasUpAction = false;        
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;        
    if(fetchedIntent != null){
             hasUpAction = (fetchedIntent.getExtra("ACTION_UP_X")!=null);
             x = fetchedIntent.getExtra("ACTION_UP_X");
             y = fetchedIntent.getExtra("ACTION_UP_Y");

    }
}
```